# MQTT - Can lastwill be sent to multiple topics?

Tags: esp8266, mqtt

I'm using an ESP8266 as an IOT device, with MQTT to send status messages.
Each device have its own availability topic, to state its `online` or `offline` state ( needed for `Home Assistant` indication on web GUI )

Since multiple devices are present- I was wondering if a lastwill status can be sent for a joint topic to be monitored ( for example :"`device_id:offline`" )

my relevant part of the code defining a lastwill for devices topic is : `mqttClient.connect(deviceName, user, passw, availTopic, 0, true, "offline")`

**EDIT1:**
using `PubSubClient.h`

Comment: no, last will is set up when connecting to the broker (as you  know), and you can only set one topic with one value - what you can do in home assistant is use that LWT topic for however many "devices" you need - I'm guessing by "devices" you mean multiple devices connected to a single ESP8266 ... actually, reading your question fully, I see you more or less know what to do ... use a "joint" topic

Comment: @JaromandaX by multiple devices I meant 10X ESP8266 devices sending different sensor readings. If I was misunderstood - I meant that I want I single topic to recieve all `offline` notification from all 10 devices ( a topic that will be saved as a log file ).

Comment: oh, so 10 devices sending to the one topic? that makes no sense ... if one is down, then all are considered down?

Comment: No. Sorry for my bad English. Each device will identify in its last will message as ‘offline_dev1’

Comment: so each device will use exactly the same MQTT topic?

Comment: Yes. A common topic for offline notifications only for all devices

Comment: I guess I'm having trouble with that because my LWT's are all with the retain flag - but if you are not using retained messages then it's up to the subscriber to deal with getting messages from different devices on the same topic - not sure if that would make the setup for home assistant more complex than it would be if you had one topic per device

Comment: Technically, as far as MQTT is concerned, there is no problem with multiple devices publishing to the same topic. MQTT is fine with that. It's just a broker - it doesn't care where things come from or what they contain. It's dumb.

Comment: @Majenko - that i know well, but can I config last will to be sent to more that one topic ?

Comment: That depends on the MQTT library (and maybe the MQTT server) you're using.

Comment: @Majenko see in edit 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Last Will & Testament" facility of MQTT is controlled by the server, not the client.

The topic and payload are specified when the client connects as part of the connection handshaking. When the client disconnects this stored information is published automatically by the server.

The specification only allows for one topic and payload to be set.

Of course, you can specify the same topic for many clients and give each one its own distinct payload, but you can't also have a unique topic for each client at the same time.

This is according to the specification - however that doesn't stop a broker implementing its own extensions to the specification to allow such things - but I know of no such extensions being implemented. But, given the open-source nature of many MQTT implementations (PubSubClient.h and Mosquitto, for example), there is no reason you couldn't extend the protocol to implement your own requirements (at the cost of compatibility with other systems of course).